# Change content and target of anchor tag on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the onclick method on a link ("MENU") to display a div (#topmenu) when clicked, but how do I change the text of the anchor tag to "CLOSE" when div (#topmenu) appears and make the div disappear when "CLOSE" is clicked? Could it be achieved without using jQuery?

```js
function view() {
  document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .bar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
 .bar {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
 }
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
}

.button span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}

#topmenu {
 display:none;
 clear: both;
 height:80vh;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

#topmenu ul {
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png">
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="topmenu">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's better to use a button element for this kind of functionality. Links should be reserved for navigating to new pages or anchors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a class to the topmenu instead of changing the style.

```
function view(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector("#topmenu").classList.toggle('open');
  if(event.target.innerHTML === "CLOSE")
    event.target.innerHTML = "MENU"
  else
    event.target.innerHTML = "CLOSE"
}
```

You need to pass event to your onclick function

```
<a href="#" onclick="view(event)">MENU</a>
```

in your css

```
#topmenu.open{
  display:block
}
```

```js
function view(event){
  document.querySelector("#menu").classList.toggle('red');
  if(event.target.innerHTML === "Red")
    event.target.innerHTML = "Blue"
  else
    event.target.innerHTML = "Red"
}
```

```css
#menu{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  transition:background 200ms;
}

#menu.red{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<a onClick="view(event)" href="#">Red</a>

<div id="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways that you can do this using vanilla JavaScript. You can do this easily by setting the `a` tag to have `id="text"` and changing the text with a conditional statement that determines what the current value of the text is.

If the text is currently "MENU", it should be changed to "CLOSE" and set `display: block`. If the text is currently "CLOSE", it should change it back to "MENU" and toggle the `topmenu` id to be invisible. You can also toggle the styling itself by using `toggle`.

```
if (document.getElementById('text').innerHTML === 'MENU'){
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
    document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
else {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'MENU';
    document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden');
}
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .bar {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .bar {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
}

.button span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}

#topmenu {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  height: 80vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#topmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png">
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <span style="float: right;"><a id="text" href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="topmenu">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function view() {
    if (document.getElementById('text').innerHTML === 'MENU') {
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
      document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'MENU';
      document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let isDisplayed = false;

function view() {
  isDisplayed = !isDisplayed;
  document.getElementById('topmenu').style.display = isDisplayed?'block':'none';
  document.querySelector('[onclick="view()"]').innerText = isDisplayed ? 'CLOSE':'MENU';
}
```

Comment: This only addresses part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using pure JavaScript.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("top-menu");
var btn = document.getElementById("menu-btn");

btn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  menu.classList.toggle("open");
  if(e.target.textContent == "MENU"){
    e.target.textContent = "CLOSE";
  }
  else {
    e.target.textContent = "MENU";
  }
});
```

```css
#top-menu {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-menu">My Meny</div>
<a href="#" id="menu-btn">MENU</a>
```